# Is it possible to use the tech behind Project Daedalus as an asteroid defense system?

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, asteroids, rockets

Assuming that all requirements are met, is it possible to use the gigantic [Project Daedalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Daedalus) fusion propulsion to move large "Planet-Killing" asteroids at a meaningful pace, be it asteroid defense or WMD?

Comment: What is your goal? Eliminate planet-killing asteroids pre-emptively altogether; or change their paths once they are detected decades/years/months/weeks/days in advance? (Timescale is important.)

Comment: The goal is to move asteroids in a relatively quick pace. This means the goal is to not move asteroids from one orbit/place to another in several years or so on but to move it in mere months. Also to turn asteroids into a planet-killing weapon as well and de-orbiting it.

Comment: The answer to a question like this is always, "yes, you're simply limited by the size of the asteroid and the time you have to move it." Thereafter asking, "OK, how big can it be and how short the time?" is always answered, "that depends on the specific mass-to-thrust ratio and thrust capacity of the engine." In other words, you can always do what you want to do, it's just a matter of plugging in numbers that make sense (or not, it's not like there's an army of fact checkers out there waiting to pounce on your story).

Answer (score 4):

How does the Daedalus Project move the planet-killing asteroids? Plural? I think it is possible, but there are better ways of doing this...

A small deflection has a much greater effect the further out you are. There are great advantages in making the deflection as soon as you can. A lot depends on getting accurate trajectory data. We have detected one or two large asteroids with possibly intercepting orbits over a year away. The best thing we can do right now is to improve our detection system. Let us hope that but the time Daedalus is ready we can probably detect a large asteroid from any direction several years in advance, and have a good enough measurement of a trajectory when it is a year away.

Nasa's [HAIV project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervelocity_Asteroid_Intercept_Vehicle), has the latest thinking on intercepting large bodies. If you are racing out to the asteroid, you will have accelerated towards it. If you are going to meet it and then deflect it slowly, perhaps using the gravity between your craft and it, you will have to chose a trajectory that matches your speed to the speed of the incoming object.

A better strategy would seem to be to smack into the asteroid rather than rendezvous with it. Nasa's [HAIV project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervelocity_Asteroid_Intercept_Vehicle), has the latest thinking on this. I recognise the approach: a similar weapon was used for bombing airfields: a first explosion makes a hole in the runway, a second explosion   hits the bottom of the crater maybe 15 feet down, and makes a much bigger hole. The aim was to make a hole so large it would take days to fill with diggers and bulldozers. In this case, the kinetic energy of the interceptor is a large part of the first explosion. HAIV is probably not ready for funding. We need to improve our detection first. But it seems possible that by the time we have good long-range detection, something along the lines of HAIV should be read.

So, why would we be using project Daedalus? I think I can construct a rather unlikely scenario, and you may be able to improve on this. The original Daedalus project had to mine He3 on the moon or elsewhere for 20 years before the main craft can start. Daedalus would have to be launched and already in space, but not travelling to the stars when the object is first detected. It could then travel out to the object when it was first detected, and before the trajectory is precisely known. By the time it gets there, we will have better trajectory information, and we will know in which way it should be deflected. The gravitational field between the asteroid and Daedalus is probably strong enough to deflect the asteroid, which is good if the asteroid is a fragile rubble-pile. This may not be cost-effective when compared to HAIV and the like, but if the craft has been built and paid for already, this might be a useful proving exercise for it. And if that does not work, they can always use HAIV.

Comment: Part of the question is actually to be using it as a weapon of mass destruction as well for my setting – Which is why I asked if we could move asteroids with such gigantic thrusters. But the asteroid defense aspect of it got me instead, because I don't see how smashing a puny probe on to a 15km big asteroid would do much. The main point of the question is that the goal is to move asteroids in a relatively quick pace. This means the goal is to not move asteroids from one orbit/place to another in several years or so on but to move it in mere months.

Comment: This is very different. Perhaps you should alter your question. Aiming an asteroid at Earth is a lot harder than shoving it away. If pick one that just misses Earth, such as Icarus (1 Km), then a small deflection will do. It has a periodic orbit so we have very good trajectory information. It will be moving more slowly than an extrasolar object, which makes things easier.

Comment: You can use gravity to pull the asteroid. This may be slow but it will let you deflect the asteroid gently. I have added this to my answer.